# Get A GUID by Type Name

Tags: c#, com, interop, types, guid

So I'm trying to do manually what AxImp does (I'm doing it dynamically).

My product is a wide released, sanctioned "add-on" to a third party product. They have an OCX, which I add to my form with a COM reference...however, if the client has (or installs) an updated version of their product my product can no longer load the OCX.

Therefore I'm trying to load their OCX dynamically. I've got everything working except that I need the GUID of one of the interfaces in one of their OCXs. I know what the type name is, and the OCX >is< registered on the system. How can I get an object's GUID just from the type name?

Note, Assembly.LoadFrom() doesn't work because the OCX isn't .NET it's COM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your comment let us know that the GUID is found in the OCX but not registered under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, we'll have to read it from the type library:

- Call [`LoadTypeLib`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/oleaut32.loadtypelib) or `LoadTypeLibEx`, passing the path to the .OCX file
- Then use the [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.itypelib.findname.aspx) method of the returned object.
- Then [`GetTypeAttr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.itypeinfo.gettypeattr.aspx) followed by [`PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure.aspx) to get a [`TYPEATTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.typeattr.aspx) structure with the GUID.

Comment: Wow! That's EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks!! Seriously, I'm not sure I would ever have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can't simply add a [COM reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the DLL to your project.

Visual Studio will automatically add a .NET wrapper to any COM object that is referenced this way.

Comment: Because if the third party updates their OCX (which changes the GUID) my program won't load properly.

Comment: @Jordan - No, not without removing/adding and recompiling. The third party should really be using a stable GUID.

Comment: @Oded Absolutely. Believe me, the FIRST thing I tested was adding a COM reference through studio.  That only works until the third party updates their OCX and then it crashes. I have no control of what they do or how they do it.

Comment: @Jordan - I feel your pain. Can you _edit_ your question and explain the issue with your third party OCX changing the GUIDs on you? Perhaps someone else has a solution (and editing the question will bump it up in the homepage).

Comment: @Oded Done. No idea how to get a GUID from a type name? There's no Type.GUIDFromName() or anything?

Comment: @Jordan - I wouldn't know. Interop isn't my thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write something like that to migrate code from COM to C#

```
class GetGuid
{
    [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern int LoadTypeLib(string fileName, out ITypeLib typeLib);

    public string SearchRegistry(string dllPath /* or ocx */)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        ITypeLib tl;
        if (LoadTypeLib(dllPath, out tl) == 0)
        {
            ITypeInfo tf;
            tl.GetTypeInfo(0, out tf);

            var ip = IntPtr.Zero;
            tl.GetLibAttr(out ip);

            if (ip != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var ta = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPELIBATTR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ip, typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPELIBATTR));
                result = ta.guid.ToString();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is code for doing what I described in my answer... except that it gets the GUID of the type library itself, not the type with a particular name.  So it doesn't do what the question asks.  Still, it's a good starting point since about half of the steps I described are already here, and the others can be easily added in the same style.